# fancy header does not work in dissertation class overleaf

Tags: fancyhdr, overleaf, book-class

As many before me, I have issues with fancyhdr. Something that should be easy to solve but is frustratingly non-cooperative.

I use a dissertation class project on Overleaf to write my thesis. This set-up is originally from Harvard, but I have altered it here and there.
Now, I would like to have a fancy header with chapter number and title at the top of every odd page (if not the first page of a chapter) using the following code:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Dissertate}[2014/01/24 v1.0 Dissertate Class]
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\RequirePackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thechapter}
```

Since it is a large group of code, I have created an open dummy project with my altered Harvard setup on Overleaf to access and try things with:  https://www.overleaf.com/5483644888pkkryhrxzpsg

I did notice that somewhere in this project code the characteristics of a book class are lost/overwritten. For instance, the chapters do not open on the odd page at all time (very annoying), so something must be overriding these things. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to figure out what it is.

Could you help me figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: it is much better to make a small complete xample document here than to use an external link. Your question here is archived forever and will not make sense if the text at that overleaf link changes

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle, I understand your point. However, I do think that the complexity of the whole project is the reason it does not work. That is why I opted for an open project so that people can see the entire code without any un-shown information that might be necessary for the solution. This was also the urgent request I received with earlier questions I posted. It seems to be impossible to please all, unfortunately.

Comment: No I just had a quick look and you load dozens of packages and \include different chapters but none of that is related to the page head, you coul dmake a small one-page file showing the problem just by deleting everything from that project that you can delete while showing the problem. Incidentally chapter 3 has title `(` as `\chapter(another chapter)`  is `\chapter{(}    another chapter)` you intended `\chapter{another chapter}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will fix the chapter title, thanks for that. OK, I understand that would make it easier to help think of a solution. I unfortunately have no idea what I can delete and what not. I can take out all that fake text, but I am not convinced that is what you are suggesting here. I will give it a try.

Comment: replace the `\include{whatever}` by inline `\chapter{foo} hello`  in your main file, if the problem already shows up in the first chapter delete chapters two three and four, the actual class file looks more or less full of unrelated package inclusions just delete everyhing not used in the example. If it causes an error or makes the problem go, put it back. That's what I'd have to do if answering the question.  Incidentally why start with an old unsupported class file that hacks some dubious code on top of book class rather than just starting with book class?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will give that a shot. Concerning the classes, this is how the setup of Harvard dissertation is provided, I did not make it myself. Therefore, I cannot answer that question. I also noticed when I start taking out frontmatter pages from dissertation.tex, the fancy header starts to appear, though not in the way I have coded it. There must be something there, that is causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class file (Dissertate.cls) contains the following code:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thechapter}
```

which means the the odd page header will only be the chapter number. And that is exactly what it does. Please note that the first chapter page (the one with the chapter title will not have a header as it uses page style `plain` (this is quite usual in LaTeX classes). So you only get a page header from the third page of the chapter. You must add more text to your example chapters to be able to see this.

To get the chapter title in the header you have to add the chapter title to the `\chaptermark` command, and to use `\leftmark` in the header, so change the above code to:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter. #1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
```

And if you have enough pages you will se that it works:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for this. I found one other thing that caused issues. When I turned the abstract page back one, the header disappeard again. I found the following lin ein style.sty in the abstract page setup: ```\newpage \lhead{} \rhead{}``` When I turned that off, the problem was now completley solved.